# replot command uses latest stats information

Tags: gnuplot

I have two data files, file1.dat and file2.dat. I use following commands to draw two functions.

```
stats 'file1.dat' u 4:7
plot 'file1.dat' u 4:($7-STATS_min_y)
stats 'file2.dat' u 4:7
replot 'file2.dat' u 4:($7-STATS_min_y)
```

Problem is that the replot command uses the min_y of file2 and applies to file1.dat once again. How can I handle this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replot` command repeats the previous `plot` command and adds a new plot. If one variable (`STATS_min_y`) is used in both commands, the same value is used. You can use e.g. the `name` parameter for the `stats` command to save the values in different variables:

```
stats 'file1.dat' u 4:7 name 'F1_'
plot 'file1.dat' u 4:($7 - F1_min_y)
stats 'file2.dat' u 4:7 name 'F2_'
replot 'file2.dat' u 4:($7 - F2_min_y)
```

In that case you could of course also use a single `plot` command:

```
stats 'file1.dat' u 4:7 name 'F1_'
stats 'file2.dat' u 4:7 name 'F2_'
plot 'file1.dat' u 4:($7 - F1_min_y), 'file2.dat' u 4:($7 - F2_min_y)
```

Comment: Thanks Christoph! You seem to be very familiar with all these gnuplot tricks! I am going to post another question about bell curve in gnuplot. Hope you would see it!:D