# how to create bell curve using a data file

Tags: gnuplot

I have two data files, file1.dat and file2.dat. I would like to create two bell curves and compare them. I have both std deviation and mean values for both data files. The values are as follows,

file1.dat, m = 18, sd = 2 and file2.dat, m = 8 and sd = 1.8

I defined my function as

```
f1(x) = 1/(sqrt(2*pi*2**2)) * exp(-(x-18)**2/(2*2**2))
f1(x) = 1/(sqrt(2*pi*1.8**2)) * exp(-(x-8)**2/(2*1.8**2))
plot f1(x), f2(x)
```

I cant find a way to associate two functions to two data files. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot files and functions in a single plot command. To distinguish between data and function, you can plot the data as points and the functions as lines using the same line style:

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#AE1100' pt 9 lt -1
set style line 2 lc rgb '#6EB043' pt 6 lt -1
f(x,m,s) = 1/(sqrt(s**2*2*pi)) * exp(-(x-m)**2/(2*s**2))
set style data points
set style func lines
plot f(x, 18, 2) linestyle 1 title 'func file1',\
     'file1.dat' linestyle 1 title 'data file1',\
     f(x, 8, 1.8) linestyle 2 title 'func file2',\
     'file2.dat' linestyle 2 title 'data file2'
```

Comment: Thanks again Christoph. My two files are identical and contain multiple columns. If I would like to create bell curves using column 3 of first datafile and column 7 of second datafile, how should I associate column numbers so gnuplot knows which columns to use?

Comment: You can use the `using` statement to select which columns to use, e.g. `plot 'file1.dat' using 4:7` to use the fourth column as x-values and the seventh column as y-values. BTW: If your files are identical, why do you need both?

Comment: sorry by identical I meant same number of rows and columns. Many thanks!

Comment: Ok, but in any case the `using` statement works similar to how you used it in your question [replot command uses latest stats information](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20105245/2604213).

Comment: I see that the pdf I am getting its mean is always about zero giving negative values where as my values are not negative. How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: If you have it defined as bell curve you can't get negative values! Maybe you have an error in your function definition.